# Mysql query on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to use Javascript, PHP and MySql all together and get some results. I've done something about it but it does not work as I expected. Hope there is someone to help me.

Basically I've created a category table, which includes catID, catName, catDesc, and catPar.

In this case I'm creating some main categories and sub-categories as well. Main categories don't have catPar values but if the category is the sub one, it gets main category ID in it as parent category. (Sub categories might have another sub as well)

I've been created a query to bring main categories as a select list and bring sub categories with another query and javascript but it does not work as I expected (It's not creating another select list, just overwriting) and for the final part, I could not find any solution.

When I do query and if there is a subcategory everything is ok but if there is no more subcategory select list is disappearing and I cannot select the final category.

I'd like to be able to put the values (if does not contain another sub-category) in stable select options, which I named it `final` then start again from the main categories.

Then, I will send them to database as multiple.

Addition: I've tried to put some specific characters for the categories just before than their name, if they have a sub category but I could not do it.

This is my `index.php`

```
<script>
function subs(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","select_sub.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Category</legend>
            <label for="category_name">Category Name</label>
                <input class="input250" type="text" name="category_name" value="" >
            <label for="category_description">Category Description</label>
                <input class="input350" type="text" name="category_description" value="" >
                    <?php
                    $select_mains="SELECT * FROM categoriestable WHERE catPar IS NULL";
                    $bring_mains = mysqli_query($con,$select_mains);
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($bring_mains)>0){
                    ?>
                    <label for="category_main">Main Category</label>
                        <select name="main_category" onchange="subs(this.value)">
                            <option value="0">Select a category</option>
                            <?php
                                while($main_categories = mysqli_fetch_array($bring_mains)) {
                                    echo "<option value='".$main_categories['catID']."'>".$main_categories['catName']."</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    <?php } else {} 
                    ?>
            <div id="result"></div>
            <select multiple="true" name="final" id="final">
                <option name="sub_category" id="cat" value="0" >Test</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Add category">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this is my `select_sub.php`

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$selected_main_category="SELECT * FROM categoriestable WHERE catPar = '".$q."'";
?>
<?php
    $has_sub_cat = mysqli_query($con,$selected_main_category);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($has_sub_cat)>0){
?>
<select id="sub_category" name="sub_category" onchange="subs(this.value)">
    <option name="sub_category" id="cat" value="0">Select a sub category</option>
    <?php while($add_to_list = mysqli_fetch_array($has_sub_cat)) {
            echo "<option value='".$add_to_list['catID']."'>".$add_to_list['catName']."</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php   } ?>
```

You can see the sample structure of database table below;
[Sample database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJtfH.jpg)

Thank you very much from now.

Comment: `'".$q."'` aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: What should I understand with that @Isaac ?

Comment: @EfeALBAYRAK You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection because the code you've posted is hugely vulnerable to it. Your site's data can be compromised.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for your reply, can you please tell me what you have seen vulnerable with it?

Comment: Building queries like that is very outdated practice. Best practice is - and has been for years - to use properly parameterized queries (which MySQLi supports, as does PDO etc.). While you're doing `intval` in this particular case, concatenating SQL out of user input like this is dangerous.

Comment: Have you got any suggestion for that?

Comment: @EfeALBAYRAK so if i understood correctly, the problem is that the select input disapears when the main category has no subcategories?

Comment: @PabloFlores select input disappears when I choose subcategory and if subcategory does not have any other subcategory, so when I choose the final subcategory it disappears.

Comment: There's a lot of ugly JavaScript in there that you could get rid of and replace with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or something like it, as that has a built-in `ajax()` function that takes care of those calls and gives you a lot of flexibility on how they can be handled.

Comment: Also worth noting, having connection code copy-pasted into every single PHP file means this will turn into an unmaintainable tangle of code all too soon. Try and keep things organized and move common blocks of code to files that are included, **especially** if they contain private credentials.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. Using things like `(intval)` is not a general-purpose escaping method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ajax call returns nothing when the subcategory has no other subcategories, try sending an empty select list, for example:

```
 <?php }else { ?>
     <select id="sub_category" name="sub_category">
       <option name="sub_category" id="cat" value="0">No subcategory</option>
     </select>
 <?php   } ?>
```

**Edit**

If you want to add the selected elements to the multiselect add a class to the selects with the categories and use a javascript function like the following

```
function addtoFinal(){
  var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("clazz");
  var opts="";
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    opts+="<option>"+elements[i].value+"</option>"
  }
  document.getElementById("final").innerHTML=opts;
}
```

Comment: This is giving me empty select but actually this is not what I'm looking for. I need to write the final result to the stable select [final] options as I mentioned. Thanks.